# Is there a Jenkins plugin to capture the trend of the size of artifacts?

Tags: hudson, jenkins

We are using Hudson / Jenkins to build a Flex application and we want to make sure that the artifacts (the swf and other files) don't grow out of control for a release.

Is there a plug in that captures the size of the artifacts that are generated and offers reporting to view the trend over time?  There are ways to view the trend of build times and the number of unit tests run/passed.  This seems like it would be a simple to author plug in that would be very beneficial.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There's a disk usage plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disk+Usage+Plugin

Comment: ... but it doesn't appear to look at size of artifacts.